# Detect which position on tab layout

Tags: java, android

I want to know or someone to give me an idea to detect which position I am on a tab layout, i got a tab layout and i cant seem to figure out where i should do what i want, i tried doing it here at an extended FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position

    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

Basically i check if im at position 1 and do what ever and then do something else but it doesnt work, only calls the code once and neva again
ANd here at an extended fragment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;

    switch (p) {
        case 1:
            view = RenderFactory.getClass("Page1", inflater, container).displayContent();
            break;
        case 2:
            view = RenderFactory.getClass("Page2", inflater, container).displayContent();
            break;
        case 3:

            view = RenderFactory.getClass("Page3", inflater, container).displayContent();
            break;

    }
    return view;
}
```

here i just put the code within each case and the code doesnt get called more then once. Any ideas ??

Comment: did u see my friend my answer. I give u the first correct answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to with [addOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)). This event handler gives you the position of the chosen tab.

Example:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current item with this code :

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int current_position = tab.getPosition();
    }
});
```

or :

```
int current_position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```